# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2014 DB Cluster server from application server .net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, iis

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2014 DB Cluster server from a .Net application.

My connection string:

```
data source=ip address; database=Test; User Id=TestUser; pwd=Testpwd
```

And when I host the application on IIS and browse I am get this error:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]
>
> SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]

Ports have been opened between application and DB servers. Telnet is working on 1433 and 1444 ports from app server to DB server IP. SQL Server browser service is running on DB server. Remote connections are allowed on the DB.

Please let me know what I'm missing.

PS: I did connection test from app server to DB server using UDL and test connection is successful. I also created ODBC DNS on application server to the DB server using the same IP, username and pwd. DSN names created and test connection was successful. I have even installed SQL Server Management Studio on application server and I'm able to connect to SQL Server DB by entering same IP, username and password through SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: It's likely the problem is in connection string. Do you use multiple config files? Are they the same? What is value of "Provider" attribute?

Comment: I use only one config file. i did not pass provider attribute in connection string. Do I need to? Also the same application when hosted on lower(Dev) environment and pointed to dev database, it's working fine. The only difference between dev environment and prod environment is, we have cluster Database on prod environment. There must be extra parameter I need to pass to connect to cluster Db which I'm missing. Any thoughts?

Comment: From your Error Message I see that you're trying to use "Named Pipes Provider". When you connect the cluster via SSMS, you probably use TCP/IP. Open Configuration Manager on the SQL Server and check which protocols are enabled. Try also to specify Provider attribute in the connection string to enforce using TCP/IP